# how to change series Column chart alignment to rotate 90 with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

```
private static void GetDataSheetColumn(Word._Document oWordDoc, object oMissing, string bookmark, string startRange, string endRange, Dictionary<string, string> cellRange, string title)
{
    object oRng = oWordDoc.Bookmarks[bookmark].Range;
    var wdChart = oWordDoc.InlineShapes.AddChart(XlChartType.xl3DColumnClustered, ref oRng).Chart;
    var chartData = wdChart.ChartData;
    var dataWorkbook = (Workbook)chartData.Workbook;
    var dataSheet = (Worksheet)dataWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
    var tRange = dataSheet.Cells.Range[startRange, endRange];
    var tbl1 = dataSheet.ListObjects["Table1"];
    tbl1.Resize(tRange);

    foreach (var item in cellRange)
    {

        dataSheet.Cells.Range[item.Key, oMissing].FormulaR1C1 = item.Value;
    }
    wdChart.ApplyDataLabels(XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
        oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
    dataWorkbook.Application.Quit();
}
```

how to  rotate series text-alignment to 90?

i am use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

plz see after and before image
[image]

[image]

Comment: you find the answer for your problem [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.datalabel.orientation%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful, but  not sure if it's only for Word Art or not:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.texteffectformat.rotatedchars(v=office.14).aspx